Infer every epoch during training with load current weight with instantiate new model with specified input shape
I have this callback:
from keras.callbacks import Callback

class InferEveryEpoch(Callback):
  def __init__(self, signal, label):
    super().__init__()
    self.signal = signal
    self.signal_len = len(signal)
    self.label = label
  
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    # Instantiate new model with specified signal size
    model = delineation_model_I_LANL_dilated(signal_size=self.signal_len)

    # HELP: load current weight
    model.load_weights(self.current_weight) # Probably invalid

    predict = model.predict(self.signal[None, :])

    plot_signal(self.signal)
    plot_signal(self.label)
    plot_signal(predict)

And here is during training using same function:
model = delineation_model_I_LANL_dilated(signal_size=512)

model.compile(...)

history = model.fit(...)

So, how do I infer every epoch and load the current weight so that I can specify the input size?
